# getting full URI + extra #segment in Apache logs

Tags: apache, click, logging, tracking

I would like to track users clicks on my website.
For that purpose, I would like to take advantage, if possible, of my Apache log system, which already tracks many things.

The idea would be, putting inside my source page "source.html" a link to "target.html" in the following way:

```
<a href='target_url.html' OnClick ='window.location="target_url.html#key"'>my mink which i want to track...</a>
```

with a well chosen key (typically, source url + link id + ...)

If the Apache log system could store the full path "target.html#key" whenever a user follows the link, it would be great, but as it is now, my Apache log system removes the last segment, and only stores the path "target.html".

Any idea on this issue ?

Many thanks by advance,
r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL segments are not passed to the server, their implementation is completely up to the client side (the browser). URL segment will never appear in logs, not will it back send to back-end scripts.

Comment: thanks scibuff, it is much clearer to me now.  Do you have any alternative idea that would work ? i am thinking, for instance, about passing to the target page the link info as a parameter instead of additional segment, something like `target.html?link_id=...`

Comment: if you want something like that what I would do is create an empty `log.php` and make ajax get request to it - something like `log.php?page=target_url.html&segment=key`

Comment: i am not sure to understand, what would this call do ? store (target_url, segment) somewhere ?

Comment: you add a javascript call to the `onclick` that would make an ajax GET request. It would not do anything but put the request in apache access log and because the segment value is put into query string it will be recorded